# How to start build Travis CI project with HTTP API request

Tags: java, travis-ci, rest-client

I've uploaded on GitHub a very  [simple Maven Project](https://github.com/Gravy94/FirstApplet) written in Java including .yml file to integrate Travis CI. 
The project is buildable manually from the appropriate button "Restart Build" on the travis-ci platform but I want to start the build with API requests as explained in this link:
https://developer.travis-ci.com/resource/build#Build.

I'm using the RestClient Firefox Plugin but those commands doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not matter what http client you are using.
You can access travis v3 API.

Request example from Travis API v3 docs [[link]](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds)

```
body='{
   "request": {
   "branch":"master"
}}'

curl -s -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Travis-API-Version: 3" \
   -H "Authorization: token xxxxxx" \
   -d "$body" \
https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/...
```